# struts 2 save dynamic table object

Tags: javascript, struts2, iterator

With s2 iterator tag, I can display table without problem. and I have two button to add row and delete row with Javascript. Below is the snippet of jsp page

```
<s:iterator value="entities" status="outerStat">
  <tr>
    <TD><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
    <TD>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border='0'>
        <s:textfield name="entities[%{#outerStat.index}].entityName" value="%{entityName}"/>
      </table>
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border='0'>
        <s:select  list="entityTypes" value="%{entityType}"/>
      </table>
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border='0'>
        <s:textarea  name="entities[%{#outerStat.index}].sqlStmt" cols="120" rows="4"  maxlength="4000" value="%{sqlStmt}"/>
      </table>
    </TD>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

My question is , everytime I click AddRow button, how can I generate a object holder for that row in server side?  how does the server side know that how many rows are added in cient side?

Answer (score 0):

As you've shown it, you *wouldn't* create a server-side object for each row *as* you click the button. You're creating a form--the server side object wouldn't be created/persisted until the form is submitted. If you need to guarantee order, you'd need to keep a JavaScript counter for the "name" attribute's array notation.

You *could* create a server-side object on the click by making an Ajax call, creating the object, and returning the HTML along with the item's ID or whatever, but it's not clear from your question if that's what you actually want to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right Dave, I need to create server side object on the click button AddRow by making a Ajax call. As I am new to Ajax, Do you have any similar code to fulfill this mission?

Comment: I just get to know that Spring offers one API to process dynamic rows in the table http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html

Anyone knows struts 2 has the similar feature?

Comment: @user1006080 I don't really know what that is. S2 has automatic type conversion, including populating lists with app-specific types.